# how to get the constructor of a class that contains a primitive in clojure?

Tags: clojure

In order to access the constructor of a class that has typed arguments, I can do:

```
> (.newInstance (.getConstructor java.util.Date (into-array java.lang.Class []))
          (object-array []))
;=> #inst "2013-04-27T04:00:55.498-00:00"

> (.newInstance (.getConstructor java.util.Date (into-array java.lang.Class [java.lang.String]))
          (object-array ["27 Apr 2013"]))
;=> #inst "2013-04-26T14:00:00.000-00:00"
```

but `java.util.Date` also takes a `long` as an argument and I wish to write something like

```
> (.newInstance (.getConstructor java.util.Date (into-array java.lang.Class [long]))
          (object-array [0]))
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object wrappers for primitives all have a static `TYPE` field that can be used in these cases.

So for your specific example you need...

```
(.newInstance 
  (.getConstructor java.util.Date 
     (into-array java.lang.Class [java.lang.Long/TYPE]))
        (object-array [0]))
;=> #inst "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00"
```