# how would a 'construct' function be implemented in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Following up from this question: [how to get the constructor of a class that contains a primitive in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248205/how-to-get-the-constructor-of-a-class-that-contains-a-primitive-in-clojure)

I know that I can write a macro that just adds a `.` at the end of the classname but I wish to have a function that does this:

```
(defn construct [cl & args]
   ....... )

(construct "java.util.Date" 0) 
;=> #inst "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00"

(construct "java.util.Date" 2013 4 27) 
;=> #inst "2013-04-26T14:00:00.000-00:00"

(construct "java.util.Date" "27 Apr 2013") 
;=> #inst "2013-04-26T14:00:00.000-00:00"
```

How would the function check for primitive types?

Comment: Add the conditional logic in your function body. Standard Clojure doesn't have overloading and typing the same way that Java does.

Comment: True, though you can overload on arity using the multi-body form of defn

Comment: So how does the java interop do it?

Comment: The introp operator, dot (.), is a special operator with specific support in the compiler, but Clojure function definitions don't support overloading on type. For that you could use a multi-method or a protocol.

Comment: Perhaps a solution similar to this would suffice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748559/clojure-creating-new-instance-from-string-class-name/3752276#3752276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the macro `new`

Examples:

```
(new java.util.Date 0)
 => #inst "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00"

(new java.util.Date "27 Apr 2013")
=> #inst "2013-04-26T22:00:00.000-00:00"
```

Comment: You just aliased new as construct. Anywhere you could use that construct, you could use new just add well.

Comment: where is the source file for the 'new' macro?